# Centering the progressbar

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar

I am trying to center my progressbar within the fragements screen. Here is what I have tried so far and what in my opinion shoul be correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pgFragment"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_row" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried deleting the wrapper layout, getting rid of the whole `ScrollView` (but as the `visibility` is set to `gone`, it shouldn't matter). The current result is, that the `ProgressBar` sticks to the top of the screen.

Might the cause be because of the Activity layout implementing a `NestedScrollView`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mediasaturn.productlistpoc.activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <fragment android:name="com.productlistpoc.recyclerview.RecyclerViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recycler" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: make parent layout relativelayout

Comment: And then? Only this doesn't change anything. changed the root layout and progressbar parent to relative

Comment: and make progressbar parent linear layout : centerinparent=true

Comment: Done. Still no change. The preview in Android studio is also showing me the centered Progressbar for all approaches. Still it won't work

Comment: 4ndro1d exactly what you want ..progrssbar in center??

Comment: Yes. Horizontally and vertically centered within my View (excluding actionbar ofc)

Comment: Check my answer. Hope this will work for your case

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_row" />

    </LinearLayout>
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pgFragment"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sadly this is also not working. Still stuck on top of the screen. Might it be related to the NestedScrollView? See edited question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pgFragment"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This is also not working - edited my question. Might it be related to the NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`. You have already used `NestedScrollView` as container `layout` so you don't need to add `ScrollView`.

**Update your XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pgFragment"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**#.** If you want to show/hide `prograssbar`, just `show` or `hide` the `layoutProgress` programmatically using `layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE)` method.

Hope this will help~